# php get local time by timezone code/digit (+1, +2 etc)

Tags: php, date, time, timezone, localtime

Im struggling to find a solution about this,
is there anyway I can use a php or js/jquery
function/plugin to get the local time of a city
or state based on it's timezone code?
For example lets say Rome is timezone 2

Thank you alot.

Comment: Are you randomly/arbitrarily assigning Rome the number 2?  **If** so you are not going to find an easy solution to this because you aren't using a standard that would be present in existing technologies.

Comment: Just an illustrative example, Rome is +1 My mistake ;)

Comment: You can't. Offsets change. See "Time Zone != Offset" in the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  Use a time zone name instead.  Rome would be `Europe/Rome`.  See [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the gmstrftime():

```
<?php
    $offset = 2;
    $timestamp = time() + ( $offset * 60 * 60 );
    echo gmstrftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S", $timestamp) . "\n";
?>
```

This function formats time against GMT, so you can directly use time zone offsets.

PHP Manual here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmstrftime.php

But a more elegant solution could be to use DateTime::setTimezone():

```
<?php
// From PHP manual 

$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look into [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and supported [timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) in php.